# How to set up a proxy for Webpack in production

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app

No idea why I can't google this, but I can't seem to figure out how to proxy my api calls in the webpack.config.prod.js file of my create-react-app.  Putting it in the package.json file won't do because I need a different proxy locally.

I have it set up in the webpackDevServer.config.js, works great by putting it in the `module.exports` object.  But it fails to build when I do the same in the webpack.config.prod.js.  How to set this up for prod?

```
proxy: {
  '/myService/*': 'https://myServiceEndPoint/',
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proxy is not meant to be used in production environment.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096

> In production, CRA produces a static bundle. At this point you can do anything you want with it. The notion of a proxy doesn't make sense there because there is no development server. It is up to you to serve the bundle with any server, and you indeed can tweak the API call URLs depending on process.env.NODE_ENV or a custom environment variable

Comment: This is somewhat helpful.  If not a proxy, then how do I tell it to point to an external API?

Comment: As it say's you should in your production environment pass in custom `process.env.Variable` for those custom environments. I wrote a really elaborate article on setting this up https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-conquer-webpack-4-and-build-a-sweet-react-app-236d721e6745 have a read.